# SFMC Web & Mobile Analytics for cloud pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, cloudpage, analytics

We have noticed that MC is automatically adding the tracking script into the CloudPAge landing pages we create.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://7326528.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "7326528"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

So we have data under Web & Mobile Analytics.

The thing is, we what to track per Subscriber ID an now it shows all users as `Anonymous` (under visitor Location).

Have found online the solution for 3rd party websites, needs to add to the script:

```
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);
```

But I couldn't find a way to edit this script, as it's being inserted automatedly by MC.

Any idea of how to implement it with Cloud PAges?

Thanks.